# Resharper 7 javascript auto complete suggests global "external" from dhtml.js. What is dhtml.js and how do I stop it appearing?

Tags: javascript, extjs, resharper

My problem:

```
something: function () {
    Ext.blah(); //<-- a javascript statement I want to end up with
    Ext //<-- I begin to type it
    external. //<-- what Resharper autocompletes when I hit the dot key
    external.blah(); //<-- what I end up with without realising.
},
```

So two questions really:

1. What is "external" from "dhtml.js" (a file which does not exist to my knowledge) and why does Resharper have such an attachment to it?
2. I did some googling but found nothing comprehensive: is it possible to stop Resharper 7 complaining about implicitly defined global variables on a case by case basis rather than altogether? Perhaps by defining them in a list somewhere within Resharper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `external` is a global object (`window` object property). Seems to be Internet Explorer specific, [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535246%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). `dhtml.js` is an internal ReSharper file where all standart browser objects and properties are declared. JavaScript is not a static-typed language and there is no way to suggest completely correct items in code completion.
2. If you don't want to declare your `Ext` in your real JavaScript files, then you can create a dummy JavaScript file and define your `Ext` there. Simply `Ext = {}` would be enough. It would work even if you don't reference this file from your real HTMLs.

Comment: Ah I have realised my oversight: the Extjs library file is not part of the web project I am working on, so Resharper does not know about the global Ext. Your approach/hack works just fine, except that I lose the autocomplete of the framework. To be honest that is not a bad thing, given how autocomplete from the whole framework affects Resharper performance.